# Rpg batch level system error?

Tags: batch-file

So i seem to find it difficult to put an 'if' statement inside another 'if' statement. I have the labels for gotos set up correctly the error occurs when the code goes to the levelstats

The code is meant, once the player has met the max exp, to go to the next level. The lvlguage checks to see if the exp requirements are met. That works fine. It goes to levelstats and then the prompt closes.

```
:LvlGuage
If %CharExp% GEQ %CharMaxExp% (
Goto LevelStats
)
Goto MENU

:LevelStats
::the error starts here
If %CharLevel%==1 (
Goto Level2
)
Goto MENU

If %CharLevel%==2 (
Goto Level3
)
Goto MENU

:: This goes on till level 10

:Level2
If %CharExp% GEQ 100 (
Set /a CharExp=%CharExp% -100
Set CharMaxExp=280
Set CharLevel=2
Set /a CharAttack=(%CharAttack% * 1.5) + 1
Goto LEVELUP
)
Goto MENU

:Level3
If %CharExp% GEQ 280 (
Set /a CharExp=%CharExp% -280
Set CharMaxExp=784
Set CharLevel=3
Set /a CharAttack=(%CharAttack% * 1.5) + 1
Goto LEVELUP
)
Goto MENU

:LEVELUP
Cls
Echo You Have Leveled Up.
Timeout 2 >nul
Goto MENU
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Well im curious as how to fix the error that starts at the label levelstats, are if statements possible inside another if statement, and as to why the script might be causing this error.

Comment: EDIT: moved to ANSWER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables are calculated once just when your script starts. Take a look ath this: http://www.ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

You need to add `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning at your script and adress to your vars with `!varname!` instead of `%varname%` when you want to get the changed values. This will always give you the last set value of the variable instead of the first assigned value.